# Compute percentage variance explained with NIPALS

Tags: variance, pca

I am using NIPALS (Non-linear iterative partial least squares) to compute first $K$ components of a $N\times M$ data matrix $X$ with $N$ samples and $M$ features. Along with the principal components NIPALS returns the eigenvalues of the first $K$ components. I would like to compute the  percentage variance explained given by

$$
\frac{\lambda_k}{\sum_{j=1}^M \lambda_j}
$$

However I do not know the eigenvalues for $j>K$ and consequently I can't compute the denominator. Is there a solution to this?

Here is my rough idea how to compute the denominator. 
$$
\sum_j \lambda_j = \mathrm{Trace}(X X^T) = \sum_{i=0}^M x_i x_i^T
$$ 
where $x_i$ is the $i$th column of $X$.

Can someone please tell me whether this idea is correct or not?

I'm concerned because I saw that the eigenvalues computed by the SVD-PCA are different in magnitude than those computed by NIPALS. However SVD-PCA works with $X^TX$ covariance matrix while Nipals works with $X X^T$, right? So this is to be expected and as long as I compute the trace of  $X X^T$ the above idea should work fine.

Comment: This is a correct approach, yes. Eigenvalues of $X^\top X$ are equal to the eigenvalues of $XX^\top$, so this should not matter. You only need to be careful with $1/(n-1)$ normalization: usually eigenvalues in PCA are eigenvalues of the covariance matrix, which is (if the data matrix is centered!) equal to $X^\top X / (n-1)$. I am not sure what exactly NIPALS is giving you, but this might be the reason you see a discrepancy.